# How to easily simulate the not-thread-safeness of this Singleton pattern?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, singleton

According to [Jon Skeet's article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx), the following pattern is bad as it is not thread safe.

```
// Bad code! Do not use!
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance = null;
    private Singleton()
    {
    }
    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Singleton();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

I have not learnt threading yet so it is a bit abstract to me. Could you give me a simple code  to simulate the threading problem (we get notified when the problem occurs)?

Comment: you don't need an example of code, you have just to think about two consumer which try to access to the same code region

Comment: @Infer-On: How do these two consumers exist?

Comment: Add a thread.sleep right after the instance == null check nd before creating the instance. If you have 2 threads coming in here at the same time, they will both end up creating an instance after their respective wait. 100 ms is already enough. You can trace it by adding traces in the constructor of the Singleton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well thats pretty simple, just let something access a property within your singleton in parallel, for example like this console app.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var threads = Enumerable.Repeat(new Action(() => Console.WriteLine(Singleton.Instance.guid)), 10);

        Parallel.ForEach(threads, t => t());

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

(I've added a guid property to your class to test that)

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    public Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();

    private static Singleton instance = null;
    private Singleton()
    {
    }
    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Singleton();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

The issue with this singleton implementation is that 2 threads can access the getter simultaneously and each one will create a new instance. So the first thread might end up with a different instance than the second one... which can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: @cyanide-basedfood why 1 million,whats the purpose of that?

Comment: @cyanide-basedfood the problem is properly recreated in this answer.Singletons are suposed to be 1 instance,so as long as there could be more its not singleton...

Comment: then i will present you with an example but please do not mark it as answer if you got the picture please because this one already does it.

Comment: I need to run this code multiple times to see the difference. A nice code!

Answer (score 1):

This is just in reply to OP comment:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int test = 5;
        Task<Singleton>[] arr =
        { 
            Task<Singleton>.Factory.StartNew(() => Singleton.Instance),
            Task<Singleton>.Factory.StartNew(() => Singleton.Instance),

        };

        Task.WaitAll(arr);

        foreach (var item in arr)
        {
            Singleton s = item.Result;
            s.MyProperty = test++;
            Console.WriteLine(s.MyProperty);
        }
    }
```

MyProperty is just an int property i added.